# Avahi-daemon and virtualbox broken after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: virtualbox, 15.04, avahi

I'm in need of help: I was on 14.04, i do-release-upgraded yesterday 2 times first to 14.10, upgrade gone ok, and later to 15.04 (upgrade gone not so well): at the last needed restart it frozen with black screen and no response to keyboard.
I forced it to shutdown and at restart all seemed ok, but avahi-daemon/avahi-utils kept showing errors:

```
$ aptitude update u0026u0026 aptitude dist-upgrade`
The following packages
Partially installed will be configured: avahi - daemon
Avahi - utils No packages will be installed, upgraded or removed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
Updated.  You need to get 0 B stock.  After extraction,
0 will be occupied B. Configuring avahi - daemon
(0.6.31-4ubuntu4)... update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are
no longer supported; falling back to defaults Job for
avahi-daemon.service failed. See"systemctl status
avahi-daemon.service"and"journalctl -xe"for details. invoke-rc.d:
initscript avahi-daemon, action"start"failed. Segnalazione apport
Not written because the error message indicates the presence of a
Previous failure.
Dpkg: error processing package avahi - daemon ( --configure ):
Subprocess installed post -installation script returned
Error status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
Configuration avahi - utils: avahi - utils it depends on avahi - daemon;
However: Package avahi - daemon is not configured yet.

Dpkg: error processing package avahi - utils ( --configure ):
Dependency problems - leaving unconfigured They
Errors occurred while processing: avahi - daemon avahi - utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) Failed to
perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Configure avahi - daemon ( 0.6.31-4ubuntu4 )... update- rc.d:
warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back
to defaults Job for avahi-daemon.service failed. See"systemctl status
avahi-daemon.service"and"journalctl -xe"for details. invoke-rc.d:
initscript avahi-daemon, action"start"failed. dpkg: errore
Drafting the package avahi - daemon ( --configure):
Subprocess installed post -installation script returned the
Error status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
Configuration avahi - utils: avahi - utils it depends on avahi - daemon;
However: Package avahi - daemon is not configured yet.

Dpkg: error processing package avahi - utils ( --configure ):
Dependency problems - leaving unconfigured They
Errors occurred while processing: avahi - daemon avahi - utils

$ dpkg-reconfigure avahi-utils
/ usr / sbin / dpkg -reconfigure: avahi - utils is damaged or not fully installed

$ dkms status
vboxhost, 4.3.8: added

$ /etc/init.d/vboxdrv restart
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules...failed!
(Cannot unload module vboxdrv)

-----------------


apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux -headers - 3.19.0-22 -generic is already the newest version.
It was set to linux -headers -generic - 3.19.0-22 for manual installation.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic
Use 'apt -get autoremove"to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B will be occupied disk space.
Continuare? [S/n] S
Configuring avahi - daemon ( 0.6.31-4ubuntu4 )...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for avahi-daemon.service failed. See"systemctl status avahi-daemon.service"and"journalctl -xe"for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript avahi-daemon, action"start"failed.
Not apport report written because the error message indicates the presence of a previous failure.
dpkg: error processing package avahi - daemon ( --configure ):
subprocess installed post -installation script returned error status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi - utils:
avahi - utils it depends on avahi - daemon;  however:
The package avahi - daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi - utils ( --configure ):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
There were errors while processing:
avahi-daemon
avahi-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

---------------------------------------------------------

systemctl status avahi-daemon.service
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since mar 2015-07-07 12:00:33 CEST; 28min ago
Process: 9734 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=255)
Main PID: 9734 (code=exited, status=255)
Status:"avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up."

lug 07 12:00:33 sarago avahi-daemon[9734]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago avahi-daemon[9734]: Successfully called chroot().
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago avahi-daemon[9734]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for avahi-daemon.service
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
lug 07 12:00:33 sarago systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.

------------------------------------------------

journalctl truck
lug 07 12:09:33 sarago gnome-session[1868]: addTab/u003c@chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:1732:17
lug 07 12:09:34 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:09:34 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:09:34 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:09:34 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:09:36 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:12:15 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:12:15 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:12:15 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:12:15 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:12:15 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:15:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:15:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:15:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:15:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:15:47 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:17:01 sarago CRON[9842]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
lug 07 12:17:01 sarago CRON[9843]: (root) CMD (   cd / u0026u0026 run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
lug 07 12:17:01 sarago CRON[9842]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
lug 07 12:18:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:18:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:18:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:18:46 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:18:47 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:21:49 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:21:49 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:21:49 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:21:49 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:21:49 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:22:07 sarago thermald[755]: Read set point 0
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: @chrome://browser/content/content.js:63:5
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: _createPreloadBrowser@chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:1590:13
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: _handleNewTab@chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:4378:11
lug 07 12:23:57 sarago gnome-session[1868]: addTab/u003c@chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:1732:17
lug 07 12:24:01 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:24:01 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:24:01 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:24:01 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
lug 07 12:24:03 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
lug 07 12:24:04 sarago gnome-session[1868]: JVMLauncher.afterStart(): starting JVM process watcher
July 07 12:24:04 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
lug 07 12:24:22 sarago gnome-session[1868]: WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
lug 07 12:24:22 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
lug 07 12:24:22 sarago gnome-session[1868]: pbsu003c@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
lug 07 12:24:22 sarago gnome-session[1868]: Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
July 07 12:24:23 bream gnome-session [ 1868 ]: Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: can not open shared object file: File or directory does not exist
```

Thanks in advance, any help is very much appreciated.

Linuxatico

Comment: Looks like you're using the open nvidia drivers (nouveau), maybe try uninstalling/disabling them and running the proprietary ones?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work: I enabled the proprietary drivers 340.76 but it still keeps throwing the same errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to the problem is the following command:

```
systemctl disable avahi-daemon
```

And a restart of the system: I also have switched from nouveau to NVIDIA proprietary drivers, before stopping manually avahi-daemon, but I can't know for if it's necessary or not, later in the next days I will try to re-enable noveau to test this.

Thanks to whose who helped and I hope that if anybody found this same problem of mine will fix his 15.04 ubuntu installation with this comand.

Sources: https://de.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=3099.0